# Facebook page tab app only displaying to admins

Tags: facebook

I am having trouble with my Facebook page tab app.
It only displays as a tab and as a page for admins.
It displays perfectly for admins but does not get listed as a tab for regular users.

I was hoping there might be an obvious fix that somebody could guess at - I've tried a wide range of things already.

I realize there is not that much info to go on but I thought I'd give it a try anyway in the event that someone else has experienced this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say admins do you mean admins of the page or admins of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your app settings in http://developers.facebook.com and

check for the app property :

sandbox mode : Disable make it enable.